# Angular 4 take times to affect new changes on live web site

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-ec2, npm

We have uploads **Angular 4** project on **AWS EC2** instance, in which we set up project on **IIS**. Every time when we upload new changes on server its take time to affect on live web site.

Comment: What changes? More details please. If you are changing CSS and JS files AND you are not changing the file name you will have caching issues. Add a version number or something unique that you change each time you update these types of files. Use some sort of file include on your build process so that you don't need to modify each page.

Comment: @JohnHanley we implement this solution but unfortunately its not working.

Answer (score 0):

it should be related on cookies. try pressing crtl + f5 on the client.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of chunk hashing. Make sure you have correct production configuration. You can take a reference from here it's for a new project:

```
"configurations": {
  "production": {
    "fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    ],
    "optimization": true,
    "outputHashing": "all",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "extractCss": true,
    "namedChunks": false,
    "aot": true,
    "extractLicenses": true,
    "vendorChunk": false,
    "buildOptimizer": true
  }
}
```

You can check [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10641) for more details.

Comment: Where i have to put this configuration

Comment: @WeeZy in `.angular-cli.json` if Angular < 6 otherwise in `angular.json`

Comment: @WeeZy did it help?

Comment: we have other issues on the live server so we didn't try this solution yet. when we try this solution we will contact you, Thanks

Comment: sorry for delay in replay, we apply this solution but unfortunately its not working. is any configuration we missed ?